# EF7 RC2 how to change targetproject

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In RC1 i could use the command dnx ef migrations add NAME --targetProject Core, where Core contained my context and my migrations. How do i place the migrations in the Core project instead of my Web project containing my DI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you use a `class library` project. In RC2 of EF Core you can't place your DBContext in such a project. This is a known issue. When you convert it to a 'app' project it should work again.

**More info & source:**

Workaround: https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/cli/dotnet.html#dotnet-cli-issues

Github issue:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5460

Helpfull link for upgrading from RC1 to RC2: https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/rc1-rc2-upgrade.html